# Odd behaviour on left join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TABLEB b
ON a.ColA = b.ColA
WHERE b.Col1 IS NULL 
OR (b.Col1 = A AND b.Col2 = B AND b.Col3 BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

I get a strange result set because Im expecting every row to be returned from TableA but the date part of the query is screwing up the result set only returning 3 rows. I know this because when I remove the datetime filter and leave the other two filters in then I get the correct results.

Really stumped this seems like 'unexpected behaviour' I cant logically explain why this is happening.

Comment: You shouldn't get any result set. You should get an error, because the syntax is invalid (JOIN without ON). Please copy-and-paste an actual query that runs.

Comment: Also, please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Depending on the specific DB, this could execute, but result in a Cartesian join.

Comment: Why is this a LEFT JOIN? Maybe you should put TableB first, but since you haven't mentioned any column in TableA in the WHERE/JOIN clauses, I don't even know how to start recommending a rewrite. Perhaps you should look at this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153/what-is-the-difference-between-an-inner-join-and-an-outer-join ... and please post sample data and desired results. We have no idea what "unexpected behavior" is, but I can tell you that if you mention `b` in the where clause, you've turned it into an `INNER JOIN`...

Comment: This should *not* execute on any database that supports standard SQL.  INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, and RIGHT OUTER JOIN all require "ON" clauses.  For a full cartesian product, use CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Thanks for reading the question Gordon...

Comment: @Vince are you suggesting that the rest of us didn't read your question?

Comment: Yep basically for some reason it was applying the predicate to my left table in an indirect way, my intention was to show all the rows from the left data set and add anything from the right data set - I definitely learned about outer join behaviour through this.

Answer (score 3):

Despite your syntax error....

You should be performing a right join because all your logic in the where clause is on table B.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLEB b 
RIGHT JOIN TABLEA a on a.SomeId = b.SomeId
WHERE b.Col1 IS NULL  OR (b.Col1 = A AND b.Col2 = B AND b.Col3 BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

However, this may be what you really want instead...

```
SELECT *  
FROM TableA a  
LEFT JOIN TABLEB b on b.SomeId = a.SomeId and b.Col1 = A AND b.Col2 = B AND b.Col3 BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate  
WHERE b.Col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: FWIW I don't agree with putting all the filter criteria in the ON clause for your left join example. There is good reason to separate the join criteria (if we could guess what it is) from the filter criteria...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - putting logic in the ON clause is sometimes necessary and WILL provide different results then putting the exact same logic in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This doesn't work either. I know how to write an outer join I just typed it in a hurry because Im in the office. 

Like I said, this is 'unexpected behaviour', my code is 'correct' just the datetime part is screwing it up. You guys are focusing on the wrong details here, but I appreciate all the help so far.

Comment: @ChrisGessler yes, I know they produce different results. But when you mention the right table in a where clause, you turn an outer join into an inner join. I think it's important to be explicit when you have filter criteria in the ON clause so that people don't assume they're interchangeable, that's all.

Comment: What's your expected output??  That would really help.

Comment: @VincePergolizzi no, we are ABSOLUTELY NOT focusing on the wrong details here. You need to include enough specifics (like sample data, desired results, and actual results) so we can figure out what "unexpected results" mean and how to make your query "more correct" - since, if it's not giving the right results now, it's obviously not "correct."

Comment: No you are, but you are also right I do need to post something to SQLFiddle so you guys can have a play around. I am furiously trying to fix it myself while talking to you guys here, apologies for my hasty delivery.

Comment: I'm not going to keep saying "no we're not" / "yes you are" / "no we're not" - we're not in grade school here. If you want a decent answer, you need to provide the specific details we're asking for. We're not asking for them to be pains in the rear or to have an unnecessarily long, drawn-out conversation about your 'correct' query.

Comment: You need to account for b.Col3 being null as a result of the left join. It absolutely is your code, not the join returning incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL would be better write at this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TABLEB b ON a.col1 = b.col2
WHERE (b.col3 IS NULL) or (b.Col3 BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

The `b.Col1 = A AND b.Col2 = B` should go at LEFT JOIN piece, because this is the correct syntax of left join statement.

So the SQL above now may be translated like: select every row from tableA and those from tableB where col1 from tableA is equal col2 from tableB, filter the results by col3 from tableB where it is null OR by col3 from tableB where it's value is between @StartDate and @EndDate.

Hope it helps.

Best regards.

Comment: This query would still filter out results where b.Col3 is null. You need to account for b.Col3 being null as a result of the left join.

Comment: Ops, correct, have escaped me that .... I edited my answer ... hope you vote up it now ...

Comment: "is not necessary since left join already make calculations on that" - this is not true.

Comment: Have edited to correct this also Vince, after Robert's comment I fixed the SQL but didn't edited the explanatory text. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue I just changed them to derived tables so all the predicates are applied before the join.

Thanks to everyone for your help.

Comment: Would be nice if you share the solution, than others with a similar problem can solve it quick.